# Integer constant expression macros with comptime assertions in them

Tags: c++

Some of my C macros, which need to expand to integer constant expressions,
have compile time assertions in them based on:

```
#define stc_assert_expr(CexprB) sizeof(struct{int _:(CexprB)?1:-1;})
```

which could be alternatively spelled as

```
#include <assert.h>
#define stc_assert_expr(CexprB) sizeof(struct{static_assert(CexprB,#CexprB);})
//^not sure if this is legal C but it compiles with gcc and clang
//(I'm using the bitfield version anyway, which is definitely legal C)
```

Dumbified example usage:

```
#include <assert.h>

#define stc_assert_expr(CexprB) sizeof(struct{int _:(CexprB)?1:-1;})
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
#define minus1(X) (0*stc_assert_expr((X)>0)+(X)-1) \
    /*an integer constant expression with an assertionin it*/

    char ar[minus1(3)];
    switch(argc){
        case minus1(2): ;
    }
}
```

Suppose I wanted to make these macros usable in C++ also.

The above example doesn't work because C++ won't accept struct definitions inside `sizeof`. Is there a C++ construct I can replace my `stc_assert_expr(CexprB)` with that would keep the static_assert semantics?

Comment: Why not use the built in C++ static_assert? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

Comment: Yep, not the same language, you should not try to have something that works always in both.

Comment: @john Please show how. `static_assert(1)*0+1` doesn't appear to be syntactically correct.

Comment: Maybe `#define SA(X) sizeof(int[(X) ? 1 : -1])` - GCC accepts, at least (of course only, if condition is met...).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array expression instead of a struct definition - negative array sizes are illegal in both languages:

```
#define stc_assert_expr(condition) sizeof(char[(condition) ? 1 : -1])
```

Comment: Can you make it behave more like `static_assert`, i.e., make it comptime fail with `argc-1` because that's not a compile-time constant?